# File download name in Chrome

Tags: java, http, google-chrome, download

I need to download excel file over http. The problem is that Chrome browser ignores file name that I'm setting in response header, while other browsers behave well.

```
resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
resp.setHeader("Content-disposition:", "attachment; filename=grid.xls");
```

Chrome saves it as "excel.xls". How can I make chrome set file name? Thanks

Comment: out of curiosity: what servlet implementation do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obtain an HTTP trace, or test your site with redbot.org.

BTW: the trailing colon in the first parameter to setHeader looks fishy.

Comment: I'd definitely use something like Fiddler or Wireshark to see exactly what the browser is receiving. Good pickup on the trailing colon. You shouldn't need it as set header will separate the key and value with the colon

Comment: Added test case at http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#doublecolon, showing that Safari and Chrome do the right thing here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just looking at something we do for downloading CSV files. We send down the following headers;

```
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0
Pragma: No-cache
Content-Length: 312
Content-Type: application/csv;charset=UTF-8
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="MyCsvFileToSave.csv"
```

This works for us in Chrome. Is it possible that the charset might be the difference?

Comment: No, the charset parameter on Content-Type applies to the payload, not the header fields.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the trailing colon in the first parameter to setHeader fixed the issue.